# Effect of physical travel on wireless connectivity

Tags: wireless, network-theory

Given a stationary wireless router and a wireless device traveling from point A to B--passing directly by the router along the path--is there a speed at which the wireless device could travel to cause it to lose wireless connectivity?

Comment: You should ask this question on [physics.se]. The answer involves the speed of light in the medium in which the wireless signal is traveling.

Comment: The answer is No for non-relativistic speeds.

Comment: I've suggested we reopen this for reasons given at meta https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/854

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not in practice for wifi: for Doppler shift you have to get about 1% shift for the channel to be far enough off to fail because the radio is out of tune, which requires relativistic speed.  But you only have to go 25 m/ms or 25 km/sec, which is fast rocket speed (about double escape velocity), and you'll be out of wifi range (say 50 m) quicker than a few packet times (say 1 ms each).

BUT

Cell-to-cell handover time for mobile phones is a practical issue, especially as cells become smaller, for fast motorways, fast trains etc.

You can easily see that if you were doing, say, DHCP per wifi-zone, with a 2-second address-in-use check, you've only got to go about 25 m/s or 90 km/hour and you'll never stay within one zone long enough to get an IP address.  Protocols for the handover have to be well designed for fast transport, but the fast transport in practice is a motorway or train line, so it's pretty easy to predict where the next cell is.

And back to wifi: although the basics could go quite fast, many parts of current standard wifi implementations are slow: scanning for new access points, establishing the crypto, and registering, for example, take about 15 seconds on a typical laptop.  Driving past 50 m wifi zones in 15 seconds is 3 m/s, only 10 kph (median marathon runner speed).  Those doing wardriving or similar, such as Google mapping of SSIDs, use specially-adapted wifi stacks to make acquisition quicker.  So sort of yes if you're trying to exchange enough packets to do something useful like data sync.

If you're just oscillating back and forth at a single access point, then no, there's no realistic speed that's an issue.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, if the device began stationary--long enough to obtain an IP Address--and then began travel, it would need to move at relativistic speeds to lose connectivity. Is that true with losing/dropping packets of data? Perhaps that's another question?

Comment: You need to go relativistic for the radio to be out of tune enough to fail.  You need to be a fast rocket to be out of range of normal wifi faster than you can get a packet.  Cellular radio needs to be designed properly so that cell handover is very fast if it is to keep up with Japanese bullet trains and Ferraris, because you might have very short times in a given cell.

Comment: Ah, thank you for rephrasing that! Fantastic information!